# How to do a Sub Report in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I developed a report in Reporting Services 2008 R2 that takes 3 parameters:

- Start Date
- End Date
- UserId (single choice from a drop down list)

And produces some data from 4 different Data Sets.

What I want to do next is allow multiple UserId choices and produce the report with one page per User. I thought I would be able to do that by using a List, and throwing all those other tables inside the list, but it doesn't let me, as it says the list has to draw data from only 1 Data Set.

How can I accomplish that? Or do I have to do a new report and call this report from there? And how to I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. However, leave your initial (single-user) report alone. Instead, create a new "master" report with a dataset such as `Users` that's displayed in a list. In that list [add a subreport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx) that shows the info for one individual user. That subreport can be passed parameters and have multiple datasets.

Comment: And that {Users} dataset doesn't need to have all the detailed data, right? Just the list of users?

Comment: Correct. Just a list of UserIds, which you'll pass to the subreport one at a time. The subreport can get all the data (in as many datasets as needed) for itself.

Comment: I did that. But in my "master" report, I'm also asking for start and end dates, but in the subreport properties, those parameters don't appear as an option when I want to map values to the subreport parameters. The UserId does, though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They should. Have you tried restarting VS yet, etc? If you still get stuck with that, it's best to ask another (new) question on SO with all the details and your debugging info.